# Where do I define method for ActiveAdmin forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am new to working with ActiveAdmin. I've read the documentation and watched a RailsCast but this is my first time doing anything with it. I need a field called "disclaimer" to a form. I have already added the field to the relevant database table and run the migration, and then confirmed that this new column is definitely in the table. Here is the form:

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Information' do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description, input_html: { rows: 3 }
      f.input :campaign, label: 'CAMPAIGN NAME',
              wrapper_html: { class: 'raw-case-label'}
      f.input :disclaimer
    end
    #other fields
  end
```

The only part I added is `f.input :disclaimer`. I am now getting this error:

`` undefined method `disclaimer' for #<PromotionalNewsletter:0x00007fb901f4a6e8> ``

Although it seems odd that this would need a method, the error message seems straightforward. I assumed I would just need to add a method, using the existing inputs as examples. The problem is that I cannot find these existing examples anywhere. Other columns don't seem to have methods defined for them.

Can someone please explain what I need to do?

EDIT: Restarting the server worked

Comment: You've done all you need to do.  Would confirm that the promotional_newsletters table does indeed have the disclaimer field, and restart the application.

Comment: Restarting my rails server did it. I hadn't restarted in a while, and didn't even think about that. Thanks. You solved my issue.

Comment: ActiveAdmin doesn't always keep up with underlying changes, usually good practice to restart after changes.  You can: a) just delete the question or b) Edit your answer to say that restarting the application did the trick and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dbugger answered my question. Not sure how to mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more way to do this

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :waylf, as: :select, collection: controller.waylfable_records.flatten, multiple: true
    end
    actions
  end

  controller do
    def waylfable_records
      [User.all, Post.all]
    end
  end
```